# How to update only browser url, not the state in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Lets say, there is application, that can be run for different units, with different names. Before, when user select another unit, we just reinstating controller, and load new data for new unit, this changes was not reflected on url. But, now we need to add unit name to the url.
For example we have following state:

```
    $stateProvider.state('management', {
            url: '/management',
            templateUrl: 'features/management/templates/management.html'
        });
```

And in browser we can see:

```
http://localhost:84/#/management
```

Now, when we go to that state, I need browser to show something like this:

```
http://localhost:84/#/unitName/management
```

For example we have unit1, unit2, unit3, and when user switch between them, url will be changed to

```
http://localhost:84/#/unit1/management, 

http://localhost:84/#/unit2/management,

http://localhost:84/#/unit3/management
```

and so on.

I can get unitName from service, for example unitService.js that will return me a unit name as a string. But I have no idea how to add this string to url in browser. This unit name should be added to all routes, but without changing them.

Can I make first function, that will add unit name to browser url after all data was loaded, and second function, that will remove that string when angular starts to searching for state by url, so instead of unit1/management it will look for /management state?

Is it possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any feedback or suggestions? Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `notify: false`.

#### Route declaration

```
$stateProvider.state('management', {
    url: '/:unit/management',
    templateUrl: 'features/management/templates/management.html'
});
```

### State go example

```
$state.go('management', {unit: 'unit1'}, {notify: false})
```